# Trouble having when removing the Widget?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

Hi i've download this one widget example from [here.](http://www.ziddu.com/download/16360591/Widget.zip.html) It runs successfully. Now, i want to uninstall the widget. How can i do this? I don't know how to uninstall one widget from emulator. If you know means tell the way otherwise what's alternate way? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: more elaboration welcome

Comment: ok then goto setting >> Application  >> Manage Applicaion >>(you can show your app )click on it >> uninstall

Comment: @nik : Yeah, It's working. Thanks you. And, give me this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This ::**

ok then goto setting >> Application >> Manage Applicaion >>(you can show your app )click on it >> uninstall

useing this you can uninstall any app.